# Renderizar respuesta del servidor con diferentes valores en angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Hola me pueden ayudar como podría hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo unos valores que me devuelve el servidor, en este caso me devuelve números como 1, 2 , 3, quiero en el frontend mostrar esta información pero no como numeros si no con diferentes valores ejemplo:

```
1 = Vivienda,
2 = Apartamento,
3 = Edificio,
```

Asi Realizo la llamada al servidor.

```
  loadDataTipo() {
    this.service.getListTipo().subscribe(resp => {
      this.listTipo = resp;
      this.buildData();
    });
  }
```

En este caso dentro de lo que cargo del servidor tengo una opción que es

```
TipoVivienda: number;
```

lo que me devuelve es un numero, como ya lo comente arriba, pero quiero que cuando en mi front lo llame me salga es los valores como vivienda, apartamento....

```
<div *ngFor="let tipo of constructora">
  <span>{{tipo.TipoVivienda}}</span>
</div>
```

Esto me devuelve: 1, quiero cambiar ese uno por  Vivienda.

Comment: Pues... tienes que hacer un método con un parámetro de entrada que sea el número y que devuelva el string que quieres. Si eres capaz de consumir servicios, crear un método en un componente para devolver un string no debería resultarte muy difícil! Tan solo llámalo desde tu html: `{{getStringVivienda(tipo.TipoVivienda)}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un objeto "diccionario" en el `.ts` para traducir un valor a su correspondiente en la interfaz:

```
tipoViviendaDict = {
  1: "Vivienda",
  2: "Apartamento",
  3: "Edificio"
}
```

Luego, en el `.html`, utilizas el diccionario:

```
<div *ngFor="let tipo of constructora">
  <span>{{ tipoViviendaDict[tipo.TipoVivienda] }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias